# 'while' loop with an 'if' function in and an error after the ':' of the 'if' function in Python

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to write code in which you have to guess a number between 1000 and 9999. But I always get an syntax error at line 6 with `if p == x:` the `:` should be wrong. What can I do to make this code work?

```
import random
x=random.randint(1000,9999)#random number
key=input("Do you want to play a game? (yes/no)")
while key.lower() != 'no':
    p= int(input("enter a 4-digit number")
    if p == x:#here is the error
        print("great you won!")
        key='no'
    else:
        print("sorry, wrong number")
        key=input("Do you want to play a game? (yes/no)")
```

I am using Python 3.6.6.

Comment: Missing `)` on line `p= int(input("enter a 4-digit number")`

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a Bracket behind the *int(input("enter a 4-digit number")*
The Syntax error should be resolved if you add it 
Here is how it would look like than, no more Syntax error:

```
import random
x = random.randint(1000,9999)
key = input("Do you^^ want to play a game? (yes/no)")
while key.lower() != 'no':
p = int(input("enter a 4-digit number"))
if p == x:
    print("great you won!")
    key='no'
else:
    print("sorry, wrong number")
    key=input("Do you want to play a game? (yes/no)")
```